# Trouble deploying EF CodeFirst to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-express, webdeploy

I have a CodeFirst web application that originally used LocalDb.  I changed the connection string to:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BatchFindings;Integrated Security=True" />
```

And I created the appropriate database using Server explorer.

I am using WebDeploy to publish to a Windows Server 2012 instance running IIS8.

After publishing, I was unable to use the application; it did not have permissions for the database.  I then changed the identity to a user account, and now I do not get database errors.  Except the application does not appear to save any data to the database.  I am at a complete loss - any help is appreciated!

Recap:
Entity Framework, Code First
Web Deploy to IIS 8
Custom Application Pool, identity set to a user account

Data not being stored in database.

EDIT: I would love to be able to simply use Web Deploy and have it use its own database (so it does not get test data from mine) but this is just so frustrating!  I am publishing, the connection string should work, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: This deployment tutorial series also starts with LocalDB and then deploys to SQL Server Express, might have something useful for you; see the fifth in the series:  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question but are you calling DbContext SaveChanges() method after data manipulation - data saving works when testing?

Also you can use different web.config files when testing (Debug) and deploying (Release version).

Answer (score 0):

So I inadvertently figured out the reason why it was not saving.  For some reason in my test environment everything worked, but when it was pushed out, I needed to add the following line:

```
db.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

I checked out the tutorial, which seemed to work until it went into that Grant.sql file.  There is no option in Visual Studio to connect.

What I ended up doing in that case to get the database working was set my Application Pool to run under a user identity I created for this purpose, while setting Load User Profile to True.  You can also run as LocalSystem (as long as you create the following folder: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop - this tricks the system into thinking the LocalSystem account is interactive).